# Pytesser in Python 2.7.9 - print image_to_string(image) error

Tags: python, python-2.7, ocr, pytesser

I'm using Pytesser for python OCR. I've installed PIL and Pytesser
and I've run this codes:

```
from pytesser import *
image = Image.open('C:\\Users\\panzer400\\Desktop\\fnord.tif')
print image_to_string(image)
```

Then this error comes up

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    print image_to_string(image)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pytesser\__init__.py", line 30, in image_to_string
    util.image_to_scratch(im, scratch_image_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pytesser\util.py", line 7, in image_to_scratch
    im.save(scratch_image_name, dpi=(200,200))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1406, in save
    self.load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 164, in load
    self.load_prepare()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 231, in load_prepare
    self.im = Image.core.new(self.mode, self.size)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 37, in __getattr__
    raise ImportError("The _imaging C module is not installed")
ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed
```

What could this mean? what did i do wrong?
I'm using Windows 8 64-bit and Python 2.7.9

Comment: By the way i was using Python Imaging Library 1.1.7 for Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error using pytesseract, which I imagine is quite similar; what worked for me was to install Pillow (a (more recently maintained?) fork of PIL) instead. You may need to change any instances of `import Image` to `from PIL import Image`.

(Note that Pillow is still imported as PIL)